# Where do i find google maps api demos?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have searched all over, found a bunch of sites but either they don't load, or they have 1 line of code, or i don't know what.

Does anyone have a link please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Maps V2 Android SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) contains a link to [Google's Maps samples and utility code out on GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps).

I have [a directory of many Maps V2 samples](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2) from [my book](http://commonsware.com/Android).

Lots of blog posts and the like are available as well, found via search engines (e.g., search on `googlemap markeroptions` to find projects that apply new markers to a `GoogleMap` via a `MarkerOptions` object).

Beyond that, you are welcome to ask fresh Stack Overflow questions where you cite a *specific* sample app that you have tried and explain **completely and precisely** what problems you are encountering with it.

Comment: What is the equivilent of ios' GMSCoordinateBounds ?

Comment: LatLngBounds.Builder. Thank you, just what i needed

Comment: Hi, is it possible I ask you a few questions please ?

Comment: @LenaBru: You are certainly welcome to ask questions here on Stack Overflow, but you know that already. :-) There are also [many other Android developer support sites](http://www.andglobe.com). Beyond that, I will point you to [my Warescription program](http://commonsware.com/warescription), which has some other options that you could use.

Comment: I want to ask you specifically. And it is actually one question. You seem to be very knowledgable, and I'd like your opinion on it. Could you devote me 5-10 minutes of your time ?

Comment: @LenaBru: I cannot provide free one-on-one support to all Android developers, which is why I steer people towards public forums (e.g., Stack Overflow) or to things like the office hours chats that I offer my subscribers. Sorry!